# New-ManagedContentSettings - not working properly under Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I have a client that is divesting a business unit into a new AD forest, Exchange org, etc.

We're using Quest tools to migrate users and mailboxes. However, I have to build the new infrastructure to match the old one.

In the old one, we're using Managed Folder Mailbox Policies to limit (or allow) retention. They started with Exchange 2007 and never upgraded to Retention Policies; oh well.

So, in the old environment, when you use a 2007 server to define a new Managed Content Setting, you can pick "Email" from the dropdown for MessageClass. This is a display name; the actual MessageClass values are thus:

> MessageClass            : IPM.Note;IPM.Note.AS/400 Move Notification Form v1.0;IPM.Note.Delayed;IPM.Note.Exchange.ActiveSync.Report;IPM.Note.JournalReport.Msg;IPM.Note.JournalReport.Tnef;IPM.Note.Microsoft.Missed.Voice;IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft;IPM.Note.Rules.ReplyTemplate.Microsoft;IPM.Note.Secure.Sign;IPM.Note.SMIME;IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned;IPM.Note.StorageQuotaWarning;IPM.Note.StorageQuotaWarning.Warning;IPM.Notification.Meeting.Forward;IPM.Outlook.Recall;IPM.Recall.Report.Success;IPM.Schedule.Meeting.*;REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR

If I take that and try to mangle it into a new cmdlet for Ex2010 in my new environment here's what I get

```
New-ManagedContentSettings -Name "Delete Messages older then 90 days" -FolderName "Entire Mailbox" -RetentionEnabled $True -AgeLimitForRetention 90 -TriggerForRetention WhenDelivered -RetentionAction DeleteAndAllowRecovery -MessageClass "IPM.Note","IPM.Note.AS/400MoveNotificationFormv1.0","IPM.Note.Delayed","IPM.Note.Exchange.ActiveSync.Report","IPM.Note.JournalReport.Msg","IPM.Note.JournalReport.Tnef","IPM.Note.Microsoft.Missed.Voice","IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft","IPM.Note.Rules.ReplyTemplate.Microsoft","IPM.Note.Secure.Sign","IPM.Note.SMIME","IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned","IPM.Note.StorageQuotaWarning","IPM.Note.StorageQuotaWarning.Warning","IPM.Notification.Meeting.Forward","IPM.Outlook.Recall","IPM.Recall.Report.Success","IPM.Schedule.Meeting.*","REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"  -whatif
```

> Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'MessageClass' to the target.
>   Exception setting "MessageClass": "The length of t he property is too
>   long. The maximum length is 255 and the length of the value provided
>   is 518." At
>   C:\Users\MFinnigan.sa\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Exchange\RemotePowerShell\pfexcas02.fve.ad.5ssl.com\pfexcas02.fve.ad
>   .5ssl.com.psm1:28204 char:29
>   +             $scriptCmd = { & <<<<  $script:InvokeCommand `
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-ManagedContentSettings], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.NewManaged
>   ContentSettings

So, the config object can *store* all that mess, but I can't fit it in through the cmdlet to create the object. Lovely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. The answer is both sensible and ugly. I put the nasty thing in a variable and then passed that to the cmdlet. I'm not one to blindly bash Microsoft, and I know they wanted people to stop using Managed Folders about 4 years ago, but what the hell.

It's better than the other solution I considered, which was installing the Ex2007 management tools (or possibly an Ex2007 server) simply to get the GUI to do this in the 2007 Exchange Management Console.

```
$class = "IPM.Note;IPM.Note.AS/400 Move Notification Form v1.0;IPM.Note.Delayed;IPM.Note.Exchange.ActiveSync.Report;IPM.Note.JournalReport.Msg;IPM.Note.JournalReport.Tnef;IPM.Note.Microsoft.Missed.Voice;IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft;IPM.Note.Rules.ReplyTemplate.Microsoft;IPM.Note.Secure.Sign;IPM.Note.SMIME;IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned;IPM.Note.StorageQuotaWarning;IPM.Note.StorageQuotaWarning.Warning;IPM.Notification.Meeting.Forward;IPM.Outlook.Recall;IPM.Recall.Report.Success;IPM.Schedule.Meeting.*;REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"

New-ManagedContentSettings  -Name "Delete Messages older then 90 days" -FolderName "Entire Mailbox" -RetentionEnabled $True -AgeLimitForRetention 90 -TriggerForRetention WhenDelivered -RetentionAction DeleteAndAllowRecovery -MessageClass $class
```

Answer (score 1):

Mfinni's work around of shoving it in a variable is probably the best way, especially if there's any chance of reusing it in other scripts/retention policies.  But if it's just cutting down the length you should also be able to use the following.

```
New-ManagedContentSettings -Name "Delete Messages older than 90 days" -FolderName "Entire Mailbox" -RententionEndabled $True -AgeLimitForRetention 90 -TriggerForRetention WhenDelivered -RetentionAction DeleteAndAllowRecovery -MessageClass "IPM.Note.*","IPM.Notification.Meeting.Forward","IPM.Outlook.Recall","IPM.Recall.Report.Success","IPM.Schedule.Meeting.*","REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"
```

Comment: That also fails for me with 2 of this error:  `The wildcard '*' works only at the end of the message class. It cannot appear anywhere else in the message class.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (test:ADObjectId) [New-ManagedContentSettings], DataValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 28092CAD,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.NewManagedContentSetting
   s`

Comment: I can't say I've heard of wildcards having positional requirements before.  Well assuming you don't want to fall under the all-encompassing blanket of -MessageClass asterisk, given the error you should be able to get away with adding asterisks to either side of IPM, granted it's not much better.